"is as much of " or "is as much a" - to place of or not?

Scotland is as much a founder of football as England

should i use "as much of a founder"  or "as much a"?

To all intents and purposes, the difference is unimportant:
Scotland is as much a founder of football as England -> Scotland is, to the same extent, an example of a founder of football as England [is an example of a founder of football.]
“of” implies a contextual association:
Scotland is as much of a founder of football as England -> Scotland is to the same extent contextually associated with being an example of a founder of football as England [is contextually associated with being a founder of football.]
